# How to avoid #ifdef __x86_64__

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am importing a 3rd party library into a dynamic iOS framework that I am creating. However, the library has the following in one of its headers:

```
#ifdef __x86_64__
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#else
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

This causes problems because my supported platform is iOS, so compiling for devices fails with the error `Cocoa/Cocoa.h file not found`.

If I change it to `generic iOS device` and build, it works, but I don't understand why.

I tried setting `Build Active Architecture Only` to NO but it still gives the same error.

Is there anything I can do to get this to compile for 64 bit iPhone devices? For some reason the library's creator thought that 64 bit means it should be an OSX app.

Comment: does it actually fail on device? or were you running on simulator

Comment: Does the library actually use user interface components? What if you try just importing `#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"` ?

Comment: It's a 3rd party library so I can't edit it. It fails on compilation, can't run it

Comment: If this is a public header of a framework where you don't have the sources, it will be still safe to edit it in a manner that actually _corrects_ it. You cannot magically include the binaries for - for example - the Simulator, though. So, if you change it to `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  
#else 
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif`   -- it should be safe and correct.

Comment: so you're saying i CAN edit the files in the framework even though I don't own them?

Answer (score 3):

The conditional statement in the third party library makes no sense: `__x86_64` specifies a target CPU, not the corresponding OS of the target.

In order to conditional compile for Mac OS vs [iOS, watchOS, tvOS] and possibly for the Simulator:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#else /* assuming Mac OS */
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#endif
```

These macros are defined in header `TargetConditionals.h` for each SDK. Here is an excerpt of the header:

```
TARGET_OS_* 
These conditionals specify in which Operating System the generated code will
run.  Indention is used to show which conditionals are evolutionary subclasses.  

The MAC/WIN32/UNIX conditionals are mutually exclusive.
The IOS/TV/WATCH conditionals are mutually exclusive.


    TARGET_OS_WIN32           - Generated code will run under 32-bit Windows
    TARGET_OS_UNIX            - Generated code will run under some Unix (not OSX) 
    TARGET_OS_MAC             - Generated code will run under Mac OS X variant
       TARGET_OS_IPHONE          - Generated code for firmware, devices, or simulator 
          TARGET_OS_IOS             - Generated code will run under iOS 
          TARGET_OS_TV              - Generated code will run under Apple TV OS
          TARGET_OS_WATCH           - Generated code will run under Apple Watch OS
       TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR      - Generated code will run under a simulator
       TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED       - Generated code for firmware
```

Note, that these macros are always defined, and either set to `1` or `0`.

Note also that `TARGET_OS_MAC` is defined and set to `1` for MacOS, iOS, watchOS and tvOS builds.

Generally, you need to test for whether the macro equals value 1 -- just testing whether they are defined (e.g.: `#ifdef TARGET_OS_IOS`) is not correct.

Comment: Good answer, but you probably want `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR ` instead.

Comment: __x86_64 will be defined if you use an iOS simulator for a 64 bit device, and then things go wrong. It will also be undefined for a 32 bit MacOS X version which will then try to include UIKit, but someone else can worry about that :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 Is this a comment to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling its because you are running on simulator which is running on your macs hardware, hence it is x86_64 and not arm64 while running as `generic iOS device` compiles it for the arm architecture for an actual device.

It does seem like a bit of a shortcoming of that ifdef though...

Comment: I can't run it. Compilation fails.

Comment: @dmoss18 when running on your iphone or simulator? or both

Comment: it fails when compiling for the simulator, unless I set it to "generic iOS device"

Comment: if you get hold of an actual iOS device and run it on there, it should work. whoever made that library was a bit silly defining that macro like that